# Determine which mouse trigger the Click event in multiple mouse using C#?

Tags: c#

Good day. i am developing a small application but right now im stuck into this problem. im new in programming..

this is my problem.. i have 4 mouse in my PC, now i want to recognize each mouse by providing them unique ID, which i already solved, but my problem is i cannot determine which mouse of the 4 fire the click. can you please help me..this is my working code.

```
 private void button2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Left");
            var x = e.GetType();
            SelectQuery Sq = new SelectQuery(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_PNPEntity where PNPClass = 'Mouse'");
            ManagementObjectSearcher objOSDetails = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Sq);
            ManagementObjectCollection osDetailsCollection = objOSDetails.Get();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          foreach (ManagementObject mo in osDetailsCollection)
           {
           // ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject(osDetailsCollection);             
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("DeviceID : {0}", (string)mo["DeviceID"]));
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Status : {0}", (string)mo["Status"]));
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Name : {0}", (string)mo["Name"]));
           }

            infolbl.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Rigth");
        }
    }
```

after getting all the Device ID of all mouse, i also want to determine which mouse caused the click..Thank you.

Comment: I try to figure out how to do it using C#, but i really can't get it..sorry im new in programming. Does any one can help me on this...Thank you.